# PHP - three CURL requests in succession: why is my code not following the redirect after receiving the response?

Tags: php, curl, https, get

I'm trying to do a series of three HTTP requests to an external server: the first two will add a product to a shopping cart, the third (and last) will add the last product and then follow the redirect to the shopping cart where I'll see all three the products I added.
This is my code:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   $params = array('productCode'=> $products[$i]);
   $query = http_build_query($params);

   try{
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/shoppingCart/addProduct?'.$query);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $reqheaders);
      if($i!=2) {
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
      } else {
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
      }
      $resp = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e;
  }
}
```

I'm printing as a debug the responses I get from the server, and in the last one I have a location, which is the one I need to being redirect to, but it doesn't happen anything, I'm being not redirect anywhere.

The same thing (not working) happens even if I try a single get request with the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to true from the beginning

Is the entire code wrong or am I missing something in order to do the redirect?

***** Update *****
This is the response

```
Response: 
Array ( [status] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found )
Array
(
[0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found
[1] => Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 12:00:46 GMT
[2] => Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
[3] => Pragma: no-cache
[4] => Expires: 0
[5] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
[6] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
[7] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
[8] => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
[9] => Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2607F8F0154DDE785B76124AE3C754E2; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
[10] => Location: https://www.website.com/
[11] => Content-Language: it
[12] => Content-Length: 0
[13] => Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
[14] => Connection: Keep-Alive
[15] => Content-Type: text/plain
[16] => 
[17] => 
)
```

Comment: Can you add the response of your curl request along with the returned headers? Verifying that the "Location: " and "Status: 301" (or 302) headers are being sent back will help debug the problem.

Comment: Try turning off `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` for the third request, when you want to be redirected.

Comment: @DeadLock it doesn't work either